# Passing Parameters from e-mail link to jQuery mobile web app

Tags: email, jquery-mobile, url-parameters

I created a web app using jquery mobile 1.1.1

As part of my app I built password retrieval functionality. If a user needs to reset their password, they fill out a form and receive an e-mail with a link that includes the address of the password reset page and two other parameters as such:

```
www.mywebapp.com/demo.html#resetPassword?x=123&y=123
```

**The Initial Problem:**
When the user clicks on the link, they see the home page of the web app even though the URL in the address bar says: www.mywebapp.com/demo.html#resetPassword?x=123&y=123 I understand that jQuery mobile does not support passing parameters after the hash, so I came up with the following solution.

**A Solution with a small inconvenience:**
I put together the following code, which reads the URL, captures my two parameters and redirects the user to the password reset page:

```
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    //cpe("parameter") will check whether the specified URL parameter exists
    if(cpe("x") && cpe("y")){
        //gpv("parameter") captures the value of the specified URL parameter
        recovery.username=gpv("x");
        recovery.token=gpv("y");
        $.mobile.changePage("#resetPassword");
    }
})
```

**The Inconvenience, and thus my current problem:**
When the user clicks on the link in the e-mail the browser fires up and opens the main page of the app, and then it quickly displays the #resetPassword page. I understand that this happens because I'm changing the page

```
$.mobile.changePage("#resetPassword");
```

But, how do I modify the above code so that the user won't see the main page at all, and go straight to the #resetPassword page?

Comment: If you're still looking for a clean solution to this problem, I recently created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an empty initial page with no content. By default do a changePage to what *was* your initial page, but in other cases, like the resetPassword case, you changePage to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Raymond Camden's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449755/1634475) and added the following to my html:

```
<pre>

<!--Start of blank initial page: #initPage-->
<div data-role="page" id="initPage">
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
<!-- /page -->

</pre>
```

I also added the following to my javascript:

```
//init page -> path control hub
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    var pageid=$.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    if(pageid=="initPage"){
        if(cpe("x") && cpe("y")){
            recovery.username=gpv("x");
    recovery.token=gpv("y");
    $.mobile.changePage("#resetPassword");
    }else{
                $.mobile.changePage("#info");
                }
    }
})
```

It's working now.